# Core Data + Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview, coredata

Делаю я сейчас Адресную Книгу, все данные у меня считывает из Core Data. С core data все ОК, все записывает и читает. Только проблема у меня с TableView.
Вот мой код

```
let array: [Users] = []

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setUpUI()
}

func setUpUI()
{
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func getData(){
    do
    {
        let users = try context.fetch(Users.fetchRequest())
        for us in users {
            let user = us as! Users
            print(user.name ?? "")
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error)
    }

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return array.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let identifier: String = "DispCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)
    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    let user = array[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = user.name!
    return cell!
}
```

При запуске у меня совсем ничего не выводит в cell.
В чем проблема?

Comment: А где Вы вызываете getData()? Как заполняете array?

Answer (score 0):

вот проблема

```
let array: [Users] = []
```

поменяйте на

```
var array: [Users] = []
```

у вас инициализация пустого массива

И

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setUpUI()
    self.getData() // вызов получения данных 
}

func getData(){
    do {
        let users = try context.fetch(Users.fetchRequest())
        for us in users {
            let user = us as! Users
            print(user.name ?? "")
        }
        self.array = users //записываем данные в массив

    } catch {
         print(error)
    }

}
```

А вообще лучше получать данные до загрузки Table View или использовать NSFetchedResultsController [статья с хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/company/livetyping/blog/309624/)

---

upd

1. вынесите функцию получения данных в предыдущий контроллер
2. меняем метод

   func getData( completion:(_ success:Bool) -> Void )

   {
       do {

   ```
   let users = try context.fetch(Users.fetchRequest())
   for us in users {
       let user = us as! Users
       print(user.name ?? "")
   }
   self.array = users //записываем данные в массив
   completion(true)

   } catch {
       print(error)
   }
   ```

   }

теперь перед тем как перейти на тейбл вью вызываем наш метод

```
self.getData(){ (success) in 
    if success {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tableView", sender: self)
    }
}
```

и добавляем метод в этот же контроллер

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   let controller = segue.destinationViewController
   controller.array = self.array
}
```

если несколько segue то можно проверить еще так

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "tableView" {
       let controller = segue.destinationViewController
       controller.array = self.array
   }
}
```

Но у данного способа тоже есть недостаток. Данные вью контроллер не будет показан пока не прочитаются данные из Core Data (может казаться что приложение подвисает). Потому рекомендую к ознакомлению NSFetchedResultsController [статья с хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/company/livetyping/blog/309624/)

---

Ну и есть еще такой вариант, просто перезагружаем таблицу после добавления данных (просто меняем метод getData), но этот метод не очень хорош тем что таблица будет полностью перезагружатся

```
func getData(){
do {
    let users = try context.fetch(Users.fetchRequest())
    for us in users {
        let user = us as! Users
        print(user.name ?? "")
    }
    self.array = users //записываем данные в массив

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    // или так если этот код в бекграунде 
    //DispatchQueue.main.async{
    //    self.tableView.reloadData()
    //}
} catch {
     print(error)
}
```

}

Comment: Это ничего не меняет, все так и осталось - клетки пустые

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под << До загрузки Table View >> ?

Comment: дополнил, основная проблема в том что у вас данные в массив добавляются параллельно с загрузкой таблицы, и тогда может получиться так что данные еще не записались а вью уже загрузился. Вынесите логику получения данных в предыдущий контроллер